# MS Access query does not append any rows as an append query, but does select rows as a select query

Tags: ms-access

I am getting really strange behavior in access with an append query.

1. When I try to run it, Access says that the query will append 0 rows, but does not give any error messages (saying some rows can't be appended).
2. I get the same behavior (append 0 rows) when I do a make table query (instead of an append/insert into), so I know it is not probably not a table mismatch in the destination table
3. When I run the same logic as a select query or open the apend query in datasheet view, I get ~1000 (correct) rows, so I know that my select logic is not wrong.
4. I checked all the indexes/requirements in the destination table, as suggested here
   [MS Access 2007 Append query trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599671/ms-access-2007-append-query-trouble), but, again, I also get this error with a make table query. So I think something else is going on.
5. I am the only one using the database file
6. I've compacted and repaired the file

I'm very confused about how to go about debugging this further. Any suggestions? (I changed the field names to post...)

```
INSERT INTO [X] ( a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t)
    SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o & p as expres, q, r, s, t, u
FROM AA INNER JOIN BB ON AA.id = BB.id;
```

**Edit**
The query works with three fields, but not with any more.

**The first 2 work**

```
INSERT INTO CC (a, b)
SELECT a, b
FROM AA INNER JOIN BB ON AA.id = BB.id;
WHERE (textField='-1'));

INSERT INTO CC (a, c)
SELECT a, c
FROM AA INNER JOIN BB ON AA.id = BB.id;
WHERE (textField='-1'));
```

**But this does not**

```
INSERT INTO CC (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, c
FROM AA INNER JOIN BB ON AA.id = BB.id;
WHERE (textField='-1'));
```

Comment: Create a simpler example which illustrates the problem.  Reduce the number of fields to 2 or 3.  Show us brief sets of sample data for tables AA and BB.  Describe the data types of the fields in those tables, as well as the fields in table X.

Comment: @HansUp---thanks, see the edit above following your suggestion

Comment: @HansUp--the ID fields are GUIDs. Everything else is text. My boss has  lot of experience with Access and says he gets similar bugs with guids. Does that sound familiar?

Comment: It doesn't sound familiar to me.  However, that shouldn't mean much because I've seldom used GUIDs in Access.  You're only using them in your join condition, and I don't see a problem there ... they seem to join fine for me.

Comment: I was going to suggest using (brackets) on FROM AA INNER JOIN BB ON AA.id = BB.id, then I noticed the mismatched bracket on WHERE (textField='-1')), and the extra semicolon. What are your actual SQL statements?